# What will be the best database for video streaming website?

Tags: database, video-streaming, relational-database, nosql

I want to work on video streaming website. But I want to know what will be the best db for video streaming site? I need to help to know about this. Video streaming site like youtube.com, so what will be the best choice ?

Thanks for advance advice ?

Comment: You should use `UDP` for live-streaming/live-chat/gaming instead of trying to find a database which is just for saving data by the way **Youtube** using `MySQL` for storing `user playlists, channels and video metadata` and you should upload your videos in other locked and encrypted server with a unique UUID and in **database-side** `(width/height/original-name/converted-variants/publisher/date etc)`everything that linked with this video.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a database is to record and relate facts and answer questions.  You can certainly capture information *about* videos in a database, like file name and location, title size, width and height, description, content tags, uploader, access permissions, and so on.  A DBMS is an excellent tool for managing all the knowledge you need to make the site work and be useful.

The videos themselves are  best served from a file system rather than from a database - most DBMSs are optimized for large sets of small values and don't have dedicated data types or operators for videos, let alone support for modern codecs and advanced video manipulation.  In contrast, a LOT of software is available for processing videos stored as files.

Comment: Nosql or sql will be better ? I want to select from mysql or mongodb.

Comment: I use SQL DBMS for logical data until I have specific requirements for something else.